# Есть ли сессии в юнити, без использования сторонних ассетов?

Tags: unity3d

Хочу сделать авторизацию через веб-фреймворк.
Обычно такие вещи сохраняются в куки, в сессиях.
Как в юнити это реализовано, есть сессии или куки, или может веб используется только для загрузки файлов и текстур?

Comment: есть например [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html). Хотя в целом никто не мешает создавать некий файл куда записывать  данные будешь

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, хорошо. Предположим я туда положил ид сессии. Как мне добавить его в запрос, а именно в куки?

Comment: Ну например использовать https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html, формой для передачи: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.html и пересылать с формой заголовки https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm-headers.html. Вот список всевозможных заголовков, включая куки https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields  ...... ... А вообще нафиг эти куки если есть сессия) И вообще нафиг сессии, если можно сделать REST и пользоваться им по идентификатору access_token например..... и вообще возможно вам что-то другое надо))

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, вот читаю разное. Скорее всего просто надо реализовать работу с куки, для пересылки идсессии(заголовки), и возможно сохранение идсессии в PlayerPrefs, между запусками.